# Define AWS database to use in Custom SQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I am creating a dataset in AWS Quicksight using custom SQL which I prepare/test in Athena. However, unless I define each join/table "databasename".table, the QS custom SQL fails. I have tried the below but it has failed. Is it possible to instruct the query to fun against a specific DB at the beginning of the query?

```
USING AwsDataCatalog."databasename"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the data preparation, in the custom SQL page, on the left pane, you should be able to choose the database name (Schema).
If you do not set that, then it will use Athena's default schema so you have to fully qualify all table names.

[image: Database Schema]